# Maintenance Mode without using Artisan?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm just wondering if anyone know's if there's a way to activate maintenance mode on a laravel website without using Artisan? I don't have command line access to the server so I can't use Artisan without first updating it on my local site and then push the changes to the server. Is there maybe a master Route that I can add that will deny access to any other routes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can just call artisan from your application:

```
Artisan::call('down');

Artisan::call('up');
```

But since you'll not have access to get your app up because it's down. You can create the functionality yourself:

A route for shut it down, user must be authenticated to do this:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{

    Route::get('shut/the/application/down', function() 
    {
        touch(storage_path().'/meta/my.down');
    });

});
```

A route to bring it back up:

```
Route::get('bring/the/application/back/up', function() 
{
    @unlink(storage_path().'/meta/my.down');
});
```

A filter to check if it's up:

```
Route::filter('applicationIsUp', function()
{
    if (file_exists($this['path.storage'].'/meta/my.down'))
    {
        return Redirect::to('site/is/down');
    }
});
```

A route to show a pretty view when your site is down

```
Route::get('site/is/down', function() 
{
    return View::make('views.site.down');
});
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! But where do I place it? Do I place it in a route or inside the controller so say I have a controller like:

    public function getIndex(){
        Artisan::call('down');
    }

This works but I can't call the up command once down has been called.

Comment: Nevermind, just if anyone else is looking, you just place Artisan::call('up'); or Artisan::call('down'); at the top of your routes file. Thanks again Antonio!!

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem. You can just reproduce it yourself. Edited.

Comment: Yeah, cool, but you'll have to change your applicatio code to bring it down. Creating a "bring down" functionality on your app will help you do this faster, if you ever need it.

Comment: That's true, but as long as I have to only update one file on the server, that's completely fine with me. So what I'd do is place Artisan::call('down'); in the routes file, push it to the server, then visit the website bringing it down. Then I'd do the opposite to bring it back up. As long as I don't need command line this is all I need. Thanks again!

Comment: in laravel 4.1 now you can up server just by Artisan::call('up'); nothing else to do :) i add this line in routes.php

Comment: It may be better form to render the "down" view like this: `return Response::view('views.site.down', array(), 503);`

Comment: Wrapping `Artisan::call('up');` inside a route in order to bring a site out of maintenance mode doesn't appear to work and instead always bounces you to `App::down`. Doing the same without a route specified but just having the artisan command defined and it works fine - any way of wrapping this command in a route to save having to uncomment the call when you want to use it? (Don't have command line access to the server.)

Comment: It's unclear to me, how can a route work and function (the bring up back route) when the app is under maintenance!

Answer (score 16):

**Laravel 5**

Downfile is in `storage/framework/down` - thanks @ruuter.
It needs to be populated with JSON:

```
{"time": UNIXTS, "message": "", "retry": ""}
```

Not sure where this message is used, but if you need to customize the message for Maintenance page, create `resources/views/errors/503.blade.php` as you like.

> 

**Laravel 4.1 and below**

Taking a look at the `DownCommand` class for Artisan, it seems to create a new file within the `app/storage/meta` folder.

Heres the `DownCommand` `fire` method.

```
public function fire()
{
    touch($this->laravel['path.storage'].'/meta/down');

    $this->comment('Application is now in maintenance mode.');
}
```

And the corresponding `UpCommand` `fire` method.

```
public function fire()
{
    @unlink($this->laravel['path.storage'].'/meta/down');

    $this->info('Application is now live.');
}
```

*These files are located in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console`.*

It specifically creates a file called `down` in `app/storage/meta`.

You could create an authorized route / controller action to replicate these commands.

Note Sjaak Trekhaa's comment below, that is the method I would use now that I've been reminded of it!

Comment: You can just call Artisan::call('down') from the authorized route/controller and Artisan::call('up'). This way it'll always work, regardless if Laravel decides to change the path or mechanism.

Comment: Yup, didn't think of that ;) It's always nice to know what's going on behind the scenes though!

Answer (score 8):

### Laravel 4

Just wanted to put this out there for everyone on the web, all `php artisan down` does is touch (create) an empty file in the `app/storage/meta` directory called 'down'.  If this file exists, then the application is in maintenance mode. That's all there is to it:

```
// From vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php

public function isDownForMaintenance()
{
    return file_exists($this['config']['app.manifest'].'/down');
}
```

So if you can upload files, all you need to do is upload an empty file named 'down' to `app/storage/meta`.

---

### Laravel 5:

Down is located in `storage/framework/down`

Thanks ruuter.

Answer (score 7):

The real correct answer to question is above provided by Antonio.

> You can just call artisan from your application:
>
> ```
> Artisan::call('down');
>
> Artisan::call('up');
> ```

## Laravel 5+

Since middleware(s) were introduced in Laravel 5, I will cover how I do it in Laravel 5.3 application.

#### Create brand new middleware

First lets create new middleware `$php artisan make:middleware CheckForMaintenanceMode`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Exceptions\MaintenanceModeException;

class CheckForMaintenanceMode
{
    protected $app;

    public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->app->isDownForMaintenance() && !$this->isBackendRequest($request)) {
            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->app->storagePath() . '/framework/down'), true);

            throw new MaintenanceModeException($data['time'], $data['retry'], $data['message']);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    private function isBackendRequest($request)
    {
        return ($request->is('admin/*') or $request->is('login'));
    }
}
```

> **Note**: function `isBackendRequest()` which returns `true` or `false` if we are either in admin **prefix** (`true`) or trying to login (`true`) or anything else (`false`)

#### replace global middleware

Open up `App/Http/Kernel.php` and rewrite foundations middleware with our new middleware

```
protected $middleware = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
];
```

---

If application is in maintenance mode (down) we can still access login page or any `admin/*` page.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () { 
    //admin routes
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and imho the best solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In laravel 5.6, the location of the "down" file has moved slightly.

It's new location is:

./storage/framework/down

Laravel 5.6 has added some contents to the "down" file, although an empty file is still effective.  You get a "503 Service Unavailable" page, by default.

Simply remove the "down" file when you're finished.

Comment: worked perfectly for my use case as well. Thanks