# Redirecting all pages in laravel

Tags: laravel

Ok
So I have a simple page with not many functions as I have been working on the front end but I am now ready to start implementing features and the first feature I want to put in is where a certified admin could press a button on the page and it makes every page redirect to a page that says the site is in maintenance mode
Now I already have the Authentication sorted out for the admin and auth is used.
What could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create this route:

```
Route::get('/down', function(){
    Artisan::call('down');
});
```

And then create a button in a view that leads to '/down'. Your website will turn to maintenance mode.

You might want to protect that route with a middleware. To go back to normal mode, you'll have to execute `php artisan up` in the terminal, since all the website will be frozen.

Comment: Thanks so much. Just one question,is there a way to allow certain people to view the site when it is in "maintenance mode"?

Comment: @RyanB Nope, in mainenance mode your routes won't even be checked by Laravel anymore. If you want a partial-maintenance feature, you will have to create it. This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21047820/943075

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will have a look at the at answer