# Laravel command lines in front-end

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to know if is possible to use laravel artisan commands in front-end or not? and if yes how?

What I mean is:

for example to bring website to maintenance mode we use `php artisan down` so I want to know is there anyway if i make this as an option for my admins to bring their website to maintenance mode by for example some checkbox?

Also this can be use for update `.env` file codes as well.

Any idea on that?

Comment: Yes you can do that, from front end. you need to call your `Artisan::call('down']);`

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya do you have any sample of that? as you see in this case I'm out of knowledge! :)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047573/maintenance-mode-without-using-artisan

Answer (score 0):

You can call Artisan from your router or in your controllers like so:

```
Artisan::call('down');
```

Beware you might get this error:

```
Use of undefined constant STDIN
```

Which you can fix by putting this snippet before your Artisan call:

```
define('STDIN',fopen("php://stdin","r"));
```

Comment: can you give me a complete function sample? I really don't get this setting about artisan commands in front-end, also how I have to define it in checkbox for example?

Comment: @robertnicjoo it's just a function call which you can put anywhere in your program, you probably call a function when you click that checkbox, you can just put the artisan call there!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But in your case its not viable. You can call all the commands using `Artisan::call('command-name')` from your controller. Therefore you can pass request from your frontend and handle them in your controller to execute appropriate commands.

But in your example of putting the website to maintenance mode using `down` command won't be correct. You will be able to call `Artisan::call('down');` from your controller as an admin. But once the website goes into maintenance mode, even admins won't be able to access it and thereby having no chance to get it up from your control panel/dashboard. Laravel's default middleware puts the site down for everyone, but you can make this work if you customize the middleware to allow admins to access the site in maintenance mode.

As for modifying the .env file, it's just a file which can be modified like any other files. But be aware that the config might be cached depending on your deployment and you need to run `Artisan::call('config:clear');` to clear or `Artisan::call('config:cache');` to re cache the configurations.

Comment: You helped me a lot today man, I appreciate that, what you say make sense, but I'm currently using middleware `$this->middleware('auth:admin');` should I add codes into this file or create another? if another can I use 2 middleware in one controller?

Comment: The middleware that handles maintenance mode is `CheckForMaintenanceMode`, which is a global middleware which gets applied to every single route in your application without implicitly adding it. So you need to modify that middleware to allow admins. Also to answer your second question, you can use any number of middlewares on any controller or routes.

Comment: I tried this `protected $except = [
            // URIs, https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-excluding-uris
        'admin',
        'admin/*',
        'stats'
    ];` in `CheckForMaintenanceMode` but still will cick me out! :) why?

Comment: You're trying to add to csrf exception list in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`. This is a completely difference middleware. The one that handles the maintenace mode is `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php`. This a core file, so you shouldn't edit this. Instead create a new middleware and extend this and make your changes. Then replace the original middleware with your new one in `app/Http/Kernel.php`. This is not an easy task if your not familiar with classes and how middleware work.