# Laravel 5 Bring site up and down without commands - (PHP artisan down and up)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-artisan

I have a Laravel 5.6 website where I want this functionality to be enabled for a non-technical admin, so that he can bring the website down or up as he want to without running any commands. 
Is there any method to do this with the help of controllers ?

Comment: normally it doesn't needed to run artisan up on virtual machine or server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintenance Mode without using Artisan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047573/maintenance-mode-without-using-artisan)

Answer (score 1):

You can call artisan commands on controllers.
`Artisan::call('up');` or `Artisan::call('down');`
you can link this in a button click or else

Comment: How do you bring it back up when it is down? :p

Comment: I found a solution i think it is better. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047573/maintenance-mode-without-using-artisan`